# radar graph in latex pleas help me

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, technical-drawing, pst-plot

I want to delete dash line and change line that adjusted with my shape similar the below picture 
the code I use for drawing 
\psaxeslabels=none,axesstyle=polar,plotpoints=45,ticklinestyle=dashed,tickcolor=black!45

and
I want to similar color for number in shape
can you help me?
thanks

[image]

Comment: Have a look at [`pgf`/TikZ](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/). See [TeXample](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/) for examples.

Comment: Please post a complete Minimal Working Example not just a line of your TeX code.

Comment: This is remarkably similar to the post [how-can-i-draw-this-radar-graph-in-latex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202163/how-can-i-draw-this-radar-graph-in-latex) by the same author. See also [how-to-add-two-lines-for-rput-in-radar-chart](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202277/how-to-add-two-lines-for-rput-in-radar-chart).

Comment: Voted too broad: this is a do-it-for-me very similar to other questions from the same OP.